# open-source illustrations of Riemann surfaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces, visualization, computer-algebra-systems

I'd like to generate publication-quality images of Riemann surfaces using open source software.  Is Inkscape the best tool?  If so, are there libraries of vector images of Riemann surfaces one can alter?